# I got some problem with '+' in node js, req.query not detect that '+'

Tags: node.js

In a part of my req is

```
search: '?nameEn=aaaf+',
query: 'nameEn=aaaf+',
pathname: '/api/phxpartner/location/chk-duplicate',
path: '/api/phxpartner/location/chk-duplicate?nameEn=aaaf+',
href: '/api/phxpartner/location/chk-duplicate?nameEn=aaaf+',
_raw: '/api/phxpartner/location/chk-duplicate?nameEn=aaaf+' },
params: {},
query: { nameEn: 'aaaf ' },
```

See that in query isn't 'aaaf+' which I want. How can fix it. Thank you :)

Comment: You should be using `%2B` instead of `+`

Comment: `+` means ` ` (space) in a url. `%2B` means `+`

Comment: you should 'url encode' when you're using characters like '&' or '+'.

Comment: i try to using %2B but it's still the same response TT

Comment: but in case of '&' in still work, i means response is &, but + doesn't work so i don't kmow why.